# ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!

Tags: mysql, disk-space-utilization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!](https://serverfault.com/questions/256707/error-the-partition-with-var-lib-mysql-is-too-full)

Hi

I am running in a problem here I have a linux instance running on EC2. All was working fine till last night. Today morning it showed me some error stating that there was no disk space to write of mysql.

So I tried to stop and start mysql server. Stopping worked fine, but when i start with following command

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

It is showing me the error

`ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!`

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're out of space

Comment: I think you need to upgrade to a server with more database space. But, I would start by looking at some disk usages to identify which tables are the culprits and check whether those were supposed to grow like that. If not, then there is more to look for.

Comment: @WhiteFang34 which files i should delete???

Comment: the ones you don't need!

Comment: I tried many of the log files but its making no difference

Comment: Please add the output of `df -h` to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the amount of free space on your partition with the command: `df` You can also check which partition holds the directory `/var/lib/mysql` for example with the `mount` command.

Many distributions have their `/var` directory in the original root partition which is not made big enough by default to hold real-life data. They usually create separate partition for `/usr` with tons of space, so your easiest solution would be to stop mysql, copy `/var/lib/mysql` to `/usr/lib/mysql` (or `/usr/local/lib/mysql` no real difference), delete the original and make a symbolic link in the old place with:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Of course check that the destination directory have the right permissions.

Comment: How do I check that with the mount command? What is the command?